# Is it possible to do this kind of HTML layout without tables?

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like to do a two-column layout with a picture on the left corresponding to a block of text on the right.  I'd like the margin between each row to be between the tallest items, and I'd like the shorter item to vertically center to the other item on its row.

[image: Example]

Is this possible?  It seems like it would be fairly straightforward using a table, but I'd like to use clean markup for unstyled content, and it is not really a table in the sense of *tabular data*.  I'll accept using a table if there isn't another more semantic way.

Comment: Absolutely possible. But I'd code it more as rows, with internal columns rather than columns with internal rows. (if that makes sense).

Comment: Good question - width on the left column is fixed.  Would rather the right column not be fixed but could possibly compromise on that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic layout... I faked images and text blocks with divs, but you'll get the general idea....

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BeG8h/)

Answer (score 1):

You could perfectly achieve this with `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` (if you don't need IE7 support):

http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/kMczt/

You could also achieve it with regular floats, but then you won't be able to vertically center the images...

Comment: if you use that it is not table less webdesign

Comment: @micha sure it is. the idea of tableless layout is just that you use only divs, so you can easily apply completely different styling.

Answer (score 0):

your pic looks like a table to me.
There's nothing wrong with using a table, but if you would rather not use table tags you could do:

```
<div class="table">
        <div class="tr" name="row1">
            <div class="td">
                <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="alt_text">
            </div>
            <div class="td">
                Row 1 Text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr" name="row2">
            <div class="td">
                <img src="pic2.jpg" alt="alt_text">
            </div>
            <div class="td">
                Row 1 Text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr" name="row3">
            <div class="td">
                <img src="pic3.jpg" alt="alt_text">
            </div>
            <div class="td">
                Row 1 Text
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

then you could use CSS for spacing the rows out, and the height of each row would equal the taller of the two content columns. I'm no CSS wizard, but maybe something like this would work:

```
div.tr{
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

tr.td{
    height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Most of this stuff would be done automatically by a table. Still, I can understand how you might not want your layout to be a "table".